# Ubuntu does not run external hard disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

This is my first day on Ubuntu. My computer comes with preloaded Ubuntu. When connected to my external Hard Drive, I got this message. My understanding is that it says Ubuntu is not able to mount my hard drive and gives the following error.

[image]

Please help me understand this thing.

Comment: It looks like it is NTFS, were you using with Windows 8 or 10? It then is hibernated.  Or if corrupted needs chkdsk which you can only run from Windows. More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I suggest you follow the instructions in the error message, and if it doesn't work out, come back and update your question

Answer (score 1):

Windows file system looks dirty to Ubuntu. This is because Windows uses a hibernation file to save the system state.

You'll need to do this in Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off` *(turns off hibernation)*
- type `chkdsk /f c:` *(change c: to the correct drive letter, if required)*
- approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
- reboot Windows

Now you should be able to boot Ubuntu, and attach the drive successfully.